# Can I charge customers at random through my online credit card processor?

Tags: web-development, paypal, payment-gateway, creditcard

I'm developing a site and have never used CC processing before. On my site customers are submitting products to companies for review. I charge them different amounts depending on how many products they submit per month. Can I set it up where I charge them at the end of the month manually depending on how many products they submit? There is no way for me to know when they submit the first product how many more they will submit or how much to charge them so I need to wait until the month is over and then at that point it is impossible to get them sign off on the chage, so my question is can I do it manually and they just get a reciept? Or how would you handle this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have them agree to this kind of payment process this is fine. Just make sure this is clear to them at the time of registration ***and*** whenever they submit products. Otherwise you will find yourself getting lots of chargebacks and unable to process credit cards (and having your funds held). Also make sure your merchant account provider is aware this is how you plan to conduct business so they're not as quick to pull the trigger when chargebacks come in.

Comment: Thanks John, I was planning to go through Google wallet. Any comments on the viability of this option with them or do you recommend any other processor that makes this type of arrangement easier?